# Django Aggregation Query

Tags: django, django-models

For a data model like:

```
class Image(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    path = models.CharField(max_length=300)

class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    id = models.IntegerField()
    images = models.ManyToManyField(Image)
```

I can get the users with the highest image count.

```
User.objects.annotate(img_freq=Count('images')).order_by('img_freq')
```

But, how would I get the image with the most number of users - the inverse of this query. Is this possible without changing the model?

Thanks!

Comment: How is `Publisher` related to `Book`?

Comment: Thanks, I got them mixed up trying use a general case.

Comment: How about `Image.objects.annotate(user_freq=Count('user')).order_by('user_freq')` ?

Comment: Man, does Django have to be so sensible. :) Thanks